# 'knife bootstrap' create client.rb in different location

Tags: chef-infra, config, knife

I'm using `knife bootstrap` from my workstation to configure a node using cookbooks.
In the node, by default `client.rb` file created in `/etc/chef/`.

If i run chef-client manually, i can use `--config` option to load `client.rb` from different location.

I want to save `client.rb` in different location, when i bootstrap node using `knife bootstrap`. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Help me.

Thanks,

Thomas Alrin.

Comment: you can use `knife configure` to configure your knife setup and it will create knife.rb and client.rb with your chef server details, you can keep these file in any folder inside ".chef" then you can run you knife command from there. `knife --config` is there to use your config path. Also you can refer https://docs.chef.io/knife_setup.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But, that is not i'm expecting. Please understand the question.
I 'm using 'knife bootstrap' from workstation, i want to place the 'client.rb' in different location in the node(Chef-client).

Comment: Oh got it, for that you need to use `--bootstrap-template` option with knife bootstrap command, `--bootstrap-template` will look for your custom bootstrap template where you can change the location of client.rb somewhere. https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html#bootstrap-a-custom-template

Comment: Thanks @Mahattam it is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make a custom bootstrap template as the path is hardcoded here: https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/templates/chef-full.erb#L227

Comment: Thanks @coderanger It helps and it is working fine now.

Comment: Actually i had issue in finding the default template file, as i'm using windows machine.

Then i found it at C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\lib\ruby\gems\2.4.0\gems\chef-13.8.5-universal-mingw32\lib\chef\knife\bootstrap\templates\chef-full.erb.

I just change the default location`/etc/chef/` to `/to/my/path`

It is working fine now.

Thanks all for your help:-)

Comment: Now the client.rb file written in different location.
But the chef-client is not using the config file from this location. It is still loading config from the old location(/etc/chef/client.rb)

How can i configure `chef-client` to load config file from the new location?

Comment: `chef-client --config=/path/to/whatever.rb`.

Comment: If i manually run 'chef-client', i can pass config file using '--config' option, but i'm using 'knife bootstrap' right?

At the end of chef-full.erb template i found '<%= start_chef %>', which is inturn running the 'chef-client' command. I added the config parameter like you given above. It is working fine. But i think, i'm doing hard code. Is there any best way to do it?

And also, 'client.pem' file is written in '/etc/chef/' still, why it is not writing in `/to/my/path`?

Comment: What is your end goal here? Are you trying to multi-host chef-clients?

Comment: Actually, cloud team is using different chef-server to provision the VM. The developer team using different chef-server to configure the application.

Comment: Yes, that is multi-hosting. It is doable but as you've now noticed, incredibly annoying and fiddly. You'll need to fix a lot more than just these basic level issues. I recommend joining our Slack and asking for help in there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i had issue in finding the default template file, as i'm using windows machine.

Then i found it at `C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\lib\ruby\gems\2.4.0\gems\chef-13.8.5-universal-mingw32\lib\chef\knife\bootstrap\templates\chef-full.erb`. I copy and paste it in `chef-repo/bootstrap/chef-full.erb` and i just change the default location of chef folder `/etc/chef/` to `/to/my/path`.

Then i used the below command to bootstrap a node
`knife bootstrap NODE_IP -r 'recipe[COOKBOOK]' --bootstrap-template .\bootstrap\chef-full.erb`

It is working fine now.

Thanks all for your help:-)